# Joining overlapping polygons in R?

Tags: r, overlapping-features

I have two shapefiles with polygons (say S1 and S2). Some of the polygons are overlapping in the two shapefiles but not perfectly. In addition some polygons from S1 are touching polygons from S2. I need to join the two shapefile but if there is a polygon from S1 overlapping polygon from S2 keep the polygon as is from S1 and delete that same polygon from S2. if only touching delete the overlapping area.

Is there a way to do this in R?

[image: in the pic-keep the yellow polygons when overlapping]

Comment: I would be happy to know if there is a way to do it in arcgis

Comment: I think you need to define better what you mean by "touching" and "overlapping". "Touching" in geometry terms usually means sharing only a common edge or point, in which case there's no area of intersection. Does "Overlapping" to you mean complete inclusion of A within B?

Comment: To add to @Spacedmans points, what about multiple "touches" or "overlaps"? Do you have anything to correlate S1;FeatureA to S2;FeatureA ?

Comment: As you can see from the pic there are several yellow polygons "sitting" on the blue ones. Some perfectly and some not meaning not a complete inclusion. By touching I mean that they have a small area at the edges that intersects.